# Grouping XML elements using XSLT's for-each-group and group-starting-with attribute when the node set is stored in a variable

Tags: grouping, xslt-2.0

I'm processing a source HTML file that holds tabular data in an unstructured way. Basically it's a bunch of absolutely positioned `div`s. My goal is to rebuild some sort of structured XML data. So far, using XSLT 2.0 I was able to produce an XML looking like this:

```
<data>
    <line top="44">
         <item left="294">Some heading text</item>
    </line>
    <line top="47">
         <item left="718">A</item> <!-- this item is a section-start -->
         <item left="764">Section heading</item>
    </line>
    <line top="78">
        <item left="92">Data</item>
        <item left="144">Data</item>
        <item left="540">Data</item>
        <item left="588">Data</item>
    </line>
    <line top="101">
        <item left="61">B</item> <!-- this item is a section-start -->
        <item left="144">Section heading</item>
    </line>
    <line top="123">
        <item left="92">Data</item>
        <item left="144">Data</item>
    </line>
</data>
```

However, what I need to do next is group lines into sections. Each section starts with a line whose first item's value consists of a single letter A – Z. My approach is to hold all the `<line>` elements in a `$lines` variable and then use `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-starting-with` attribute to identify the element starting a new section.

The respective XSLT fragment looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$lines/line" group-starting-with="...pattern here...">
    <section>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </section>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

The problem is I can't figure out a working pattern to identify section starts. The best I could do was ensuring that `//line/item[1]/text()[matches(., '^[A-Z]$')]` works when used separately in an XPath evaluator. However, I can't seem to derive a working version to be used with `group-starting-with`.

*Update* Hence the wanted result should look like this:

```
<data>
    <section> <!-- this section started automatically because of being at the beginning -->
        <line top="44">
             <item left="294">Some heading text</item>
        </line>
    </section>
    <section>
        <line top="47">
             <item left="718">A</item> <!-- this item is a section-start -->
             <item left="764">Section heading</item>
        </line>
        <line top="78">
            <item left="92">Data</item>
            <item left="144">Data</item>
            <item left="540">Data</item>
            <item left="588">Data</item>
        </line>
    </section>
    <section>
        <line top="101">
            <item left="61">B</item> <!-- this item is a section-start -->
            <item left="144">Section heading</item>
        </line>
        <line top="123">
            <item left="92">Data</item>
            <item left="144">Data</item>
        </line>
    </section>
</data>
```

Comment: So, what should the wanted result be? Missing it makes the question rather unclear.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I thought it was clear from the xslt fragment. Updated the question anyway.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Let me emphasize what's written in the question: *whose first item contains a **single** letter A – Z*.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Well a simple answer would be a lot more useful than arguing my wordings.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - There are plenty of better ways to ask for clarification than how you've done it here. Your edit was also unnecessarily harsh. Could you please be a little more polite when interacting with people who are making a legitimate effort to get help?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - There seems to be some disagreement about the wording here, so it's not clear that your addition enhances the question. Also, the way you went about it was insulting to the asker and completely inappropriate. We're trying to help people, not drive them away: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The point is people aren't machines. If we were, our questions would be perfect and unambiguous; whatsoever, we might not need to ask at all. Btw. I didn't refuse to make an edit, refusal is just *your personal interpretation*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$lines/line" group-starting-with="line[matches(child::item[1], '^[A-Z]$')]">
    <section name="{current-group()[1]/item[1]}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </section>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

The trick is really understanding that `group-starting-with` shall be a *pattern* not a *condition*.