# XSLT 2 or 3 - Add structure to a flat XML file using for-each-group : group-starting-with

Tags: grouping, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I've been given an [Verity .otl](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E05317_01/psft/acrobat/dm0682.pdf) file and have been asked to "decode" so all the rules can be remade.

I naturally thought take the text file and convert it to XML and process it. My first pass creates XML and adds useful attributes.  Here is  an example of the output of my 1st pass.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>  
     <line pos="1" Lv="1" val="# topic_OST_Agri_export |Or|"/>
     <line pos="2" Lv="2" val="## topic_OST_Export_contracts |Or|"/>
     <line pos="3" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|"/>
     <line pos="4" Lv="4" val="#### ~export~"/>
     <line pos="5" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~contract#~"/>
     <line pos="6" Lv="3" val="### ~contract for the export~"/>
     <line pos="7" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|"/>
     <line pos="8" Lv="4" val="#### ~contract~"/>
     <line pos="9" Lv="4" val="#### ~for~"/>
     <line pos="10" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
     <line pos="11" Lv="2" val="## topic_OST_Export_figures |Or|"/>
     <line pos="12" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|"/>
     <line pos="13" Lv="4" val="#### ~export~"/>
     <line pos="14" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~figure#~"/>
     <line pos="15" Lv="3" val="### ~export statistics~"/>
     <line pos="16" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|"/>
     <line pos="17" Lv="4" val="#### ~Agriculturle~"/>
     <line pos="18" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
     <line pos="19" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~increas#~"/>
     <line pos="20" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|"/>
     <line pos="21" Lv="4" val="#### ~defence~"/>
     <line pos="22" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
     <line pos="23" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~reach#~"/>
     <line pos="24" Lv="3" val="### |Near/6|"/>
     <line pos="25" Lv="4" val="#### |Phrase|"/>
     <line pos="26" Lv="5" val="##### ~Agri~"/>
     <line pos="27" Lv="5" val="##### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
     <line pos="28" Lv="4" val="#### |Any|"/>
     <line pos="29" Lv="5" val="##### ~statistics~"/>
     <line pos="30" Lv="5" val="##### ~trends~"/>
     <line pos="31" Lv="5" val="##### ~figures~"/>
     <line pos="32" Lv="5" val="##### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~annual#~"/>
     <line pos="33" Lv="5" val="##### ~per cent~"/>
     <line pos="34" Lv="5" val="##### ~million~"/>
     <line pos="35" Lv="5" val="##### ~billion~"/>
     <line pos="36" Lv="2" val="## ~Agri export~"/>
     <line pos="37" Lv="2" val="## ~Agri exports~"/>
   <line pos="38" Lv="2" val="## ~exporting Agri~"/>
</root>
```

This is just one snippet of a file with 70k lines.

I'd like to convert this into an xml structure that groups the lines according to their @Lv

An example from above would be ( @Type and @calledFrom are added by me in my unsuccessful attempts to understand the data and achieve the goal)

```
 <line pos="1" Lv="1" val="# topic_OST_Agri_export |Or|">
  
     <line pos="2" Lv="2" val="## topic_OST_Export_contracts |Or|" Type="Topic"
           calledFrom="1">
        <line pos="3" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|" Type="phrase">
           <line pos="4" Lv="4" val="#### ~export~" Type="Word"/>
           <line pos="5" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~contract#~" Type="Wildcard"/>
           <line pos="6" Lv="3" val="### ~contract for the export~" Type="Word"/>
           <line pos="7" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|" Type="phrase">
              <line pos="8" Lv="4" val="#### ~contract~" Type="Word"/>
              <line pos="9" Lv="4" val="#### ~for~" Type="Word"/>
              <line pos="10" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~" Type="Wildcard"/>
           </line>
        </line>
     </line>
```

What have I already failed at?

Recursion: xsl:Chosing on different @Types.  This looked promising but failed due to gobbling up subsequent lines when they shouldn't have.

I feel group-starting-with is the answer to structure the data for further processing and understanding but after a day I just don't "get" group-starting-with.

The last post I read on Stack Overflow on a similar question ended

> "The trick is really understanding that group-starting-with shall be a
> pattern not a condition."
> Blockquote
> Blockquote

Source: [grouping-xml-elements-using-xslts-for-each-group-and-group-starting-with-attrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695510/grouping-xml-elements-using-xslts-for-each-group-and-group-starting-with-attrib)

Any guidance on how to test following siblings Attribute and test if they are required in the group would be, of course most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Question about the desired output...why are Lv="3" lines children of other Lv="3" lines? Wouldn't they be siblings?

If they should be siblings, you could do a recursive template call that just gets the next level.

Example...

**XSLT 3.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="nest_levels">
                <xsl:with-param name="ctx" select="line"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="current_level" select="1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="nest_levels">
        <xsl:param name="ctx" required="yes" as="element()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="current_level" required="yes" as="xs:double"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$ctx[@Lv=$current_level]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                <xsl:if test="following-sibling::line[1]/@Lv > $current_level">
                    <xsl:call-template name="nest_levels">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ctx" select="following-sibling::line[preceding-sibling::line[@Lv=$current_level][1] is current()]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="current_level" select="following-sibling::line[1]/@Lv"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```xml
<root>
   <line pos="1" Lv="1" val="# topic_OST_Agri_export |Or|">
      <line pos="2" Lv="2" val="## topic_OST_Export_contracts |Or|">
         <line pos="3" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|">
            <line pos="4" Lv="4" val="#### ~export~"/>
            <line pos="5" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~contract#~"/>
         </line>
         <line pos="6" Lv="3" val="### ~contract for the export~"/>
         <line pos="7" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|">
            <line pos="8" Lv="4" val="#### ~contract~"/>
            <line pos="9" Lv="4" val="#### ~for~"/>
            <line pos="10" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
         </line>
      </line>
      <line pos="11" Lv="2" val="## topic_OST_Export_figures |Or|">
         <line pos="12" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|">
            <line pos="13" Lv="4" val="#### ~export~"/>
            <line pos="14" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~figure#~"/>
         </line>
         <line pos="15" Lv="3" val="### ~export statistics~"/>
         <line pos="16" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|">
            <line pos="17" Lv="4" val="#### ~Agriculturle~"/>
            <line pos="18" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
            <line pos="19" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~increas#~"/>
         </line>
         <line pos="20" Lv="3" val="### |Phrase|">
            <line pos="21" Lv="4" val="#### ~defence~"/>
            <line pos="22" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
            <line pos="23" Lv="4" val="#### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~reach#~"/>
         </line>
         <line pos="24" Lv="3" val="### |Near/6|">
            <line pos="25" Lv="4" val="#### |Phrase|">
               <line pos="26" Lv="5" val="##### ~Agri~"/>
               <line pos="27" Lv="5" val="##### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~export#~"/>
            </line>
            <line pos="28" Lv="4" val="#### |Any|">
               <line pos="29" Lv="5" val="##### ~statistics~"/>
               <line pos="30" Lv="5" val="##### ~trends~"/>
               <line pos="31" Lv="5" val="##### ~figures~"/>
               <line pos="32" Lv="5" val="##### |Wildcard| /wordtext = ~annual#~"/>
               <line pos="33" Lv="5" val="##### ~per cent~"/>
               <line pos="34" Lv="5" val="##### ~million~"/>
               <line pos="35" Lv="5" val="##### ~billion~"/>
            </line>
         </line>
      </line>
      <line pos="36" Lv="2" val="## ~Agri export~"/>
      <line pos="37" Lv="2" val="## ~Agri exports~"/>
      <line pos="38" Lv="2" val="## ~exporting Agri~"/>
   </line>
</root>
```

Comment: Great question Daniel, I've been asking myself that a few times today, I can only guess the order of the words/phases is important in the construction of the Boolean search that this OFT file is supposed to make "easier".

Thankyou for your answer I will test and be back soon.

Comment: Kind of an odd way to use "grouping" (with a pattern that does never match); it seems you could just use `<xsl:for-each select="$ctx[@Lv=$current_level]">` instead of that odd `<xsl:for-each-group select="$ctx[@Lv=$current_level]" group-starting-with="@Lv"><xsl:for-each select="current-group()">` combo.

Comment: Good point @MartinHonnen. I did copy this from some existing code I had that did something similar, so it could've been a remnant of something else I had tried with actual grouping. I've updated my answer with the for-each-group removed.